# Making multiple wireless networks into 1

Tags: windows-7, networking, bridging

Aloha,

Is there a way to do the following?:

I have 3 networks on my PC, 2x wireless mobile broadband (with both 7.2mbit) at 60ms ping each, and a 3rd wireless network from my 5mbit LAN connection

I want to share all together so it becomes 19.4 mbit (which it is in total) as one wireless network..

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the bandwidth of three networks into one network is not practical at the OS or user level.  Both ends of all three wireless networks would need to know that they are part of this combined network.

802.11 g and n does something similar called *channel bonding* to increase bandwidth.  But this is performed at a very low layer in the protocol stack (at each end), so that all the messy details and error recovery that might be needed when one channel does not keep up with the other channel can be hidden from the upper protocol layers.